# python3 function not defined even though it is

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

when I try to call the changeProfile function, I keep getting the error "getAuthCode is not defined" even though it is clearly defined. Why do I keep getting this error? What am I doing wrong? It used to work from what I remember, but now all of a sudden it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
import os,re,json,socket,random,select,threading,time,sys
import urllib.request as urlreq
from urllib.request import quote,unquote
import urllib.parse
class miscellanous:
    """Main class."""
    def __init__():
        """What to do on initalizing."""
        pass
    def getAuthCode(u, p):
        """Get authentification code from username and password specified."""
        try:
            data=urllib.request.urlopen('http://chatango.com/login',urllib.parse.urlencode({'user_id': u, 'password': p, 'storecookie': 'on', 'checkerrors': 'yes'}).encode()).headers
        except Exception as e: print("Error: Auth request: %s" % e)
        for x, y in data.items():
            if x.lower() == 'set-cookie':
                returned = re.compile(r"auth\.chatango\.com ?= ?([^;]*)", re.IGNORECASE).search(y)
                if returned:
                    ret = returned.group(1)
                    if ret == "": raise ValueError("Error: Unable to get auth: Error in username/password.")
                    return ret


    def createAccount(u, p):
        """Create an account with the username and password specified."""
        try:
            resp=urllib.request.urlopen("http://chatango.com/signupdir", urllib.parse.urlencode({"email": "accmaker"+str(random.randrange(1,1000000000000))+"@hotmail.com", "login": u, "password": p, "password_confirm": p, "storecookie": "on", "checkerrors": "yes"}).encode())
            fu=str(resp.read())
            resp.close()
            if "screen name has been" in fu: r = "Error: User could not be created: Already exists."
            else: r = "The user was created. If it didn't work, try another username."
            return r
        except: return "Error: Invalid or missing arguments."
    def createGroup(u, p, g, d="Description.", m="Owner message."):
        """Creates a group with the username, password, group name, description and owner message specified."""
        try:
            g=g.replace(" ","-")
            resp=urllib.request.urlopen("http://chatango.com/creategrouplogin",urllib.parse.urlencode({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0", "uns": "0", "p": p, "lo": u, "d": d, "u": g, "n": m}).encode())
            fu=str(resp.read())
            resp.close()
            if "groupexists" in fu: r = "Error: Group could not be created: Already exists."
            else: r = "The group was created. If it didn't work, try another group name. Click <a href='http://%s.chatango.com/' target='_blank'>[[here]]<a> to get to the new group."
            return r
        except: return "Error: Invalid or missing arguments."
    def changeProfile(u, p, m="Default", e="accmaker"+str(random.randrange(1,1000000000000))+"@hotmail.com", l="Norway", g="M", a="18"):
        try:
            resp = urlreq.urlopen('http://'+u.lower()+'.chatango.com/updateprofile?&d&pic&s='+getAuthCode(u, p), urllib.parse.urlencode({"show_friends": "checked", "dir": "checked", "checkerrors": "yes", "uns": "1", "line": m, "email": e, "location": l, "gender": g, "age": a}).encode())
            return "The profile change was successful."
        except Exception as e:
            return "%s" % e
    def checkOnlineStatus(u):
        """Check if the predefined username is online or offline."""
        if "Chat with" in urlreq.urlopen("http://"+u.lower()+".chatango.com").read().decode(): return '<b><font color="#00ff00">Online</font></b>'
        else: return "<b><font color='#ff0000'>Offline</font></b>"
        resp.close()
    def checkUserGender(u):
        """Get the gender for the predefined username."""
        resp=urlreq.urlopen("http://st.chatango.com/profileimg/%s/%s/%s/mod1.xml" % (u.lower()[0], u.lower()[1], u.lower()))
        try: ru=re.compile(r'<s>(.*?)</s>', re.IGNORECASE).search(resp.read().decode()).group(1)
        except: ru="?"
        ret=unquote(ru)
        resp.close()
        if ret=="M": r="Male"
        elif ret=="F": r="Female"
        elif ret=="?": r="Not specified"        
        return r
    def changeBackGround(u, p, x, transparency=None):
        """Update the user's bg using the predefined username, password and bg color."""
        color=quote(x.split()[0])
        try: image=x.split()[1]
        except: image=None
        if color and len(color)==1:
            color=color*6
        if color and len(color)==3:
            color+=color
        elif color and len(color)!=6:
            return False
        if transparency!=None and abs(transparency)>1:
            transparency = abs(transparency) / 100
        data=urllib.request.urlopen("http://fp.chatango.com/profileimg/%s/%s/%s/msgbg.xml" % (u[0], u[1], u.lower())).read().decode()
        data=dict([x.replace('"', '').split("=") for x in re.findall('(\w+=".*?")', data)[1:]])
        data["p"]=p
        data["lo"]=u
        if color: data["bgc"] = color
        if transparency!=None: data["bgalp"]=abs(transparency) * 100
        if image!=None: data["useimg"]=1 if bool(image) else 0
        data12=urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
        data13=data12.encode()
        der=urllib.request.urlopen("http://chatango.com/updatemsgbg", data13).read()
    def checkIfGroupExists(g):
        """Check if the predefined group exists."""
        i = urlreq.urlopen('http://'+g+'.chatango.com').read().decode()
        if '<table id="group_table"' in i: return True#"This chat does exist!"
        else: return False#"This chat doesn't exist."
        i.close()
```

Comment: Post the full traceback please.

Comment: Stop. Stop. [Go back and read.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) You're missing several fundamentals.

Comment: Is it a instance method for the class if it is you are missing a  self. Should be self.getAuthcode() also for all the methods Did you forget to add  a `self` in the object methods  ?https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html this might help specifically class and instance variables. The link is for 2.7.9

Comment: wow your code is like a python car crash! You have violated pretty much every pep8 standard.  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1):

All of the functions you've shown are part of the `miscellaneous` class, so to access them, you need to prefix them with the class name. To refer to the `getAuthCode` function, you'd use `miscellaneous.getAuthCode`.

But, it doesn't seem like you should really be using a class here. You never create instances of `miscellaneous`, nor are the functions set up to be run as methods. So, probably the right answer is to get rid of the `class miscellaneous:` declaration at the top of the file, and then to unindent all the functions one level.

(Note, in Python 2 you'd have an additional issue if you kept the class: Unbound methods required that their first argument be an instance of their class (or a subclass). In that situation, you'd need to use the `staticmethod` decorator on any functions that did not expect to get an instance at all.)

Comment: in python 3 you can just call on the class rather than an instance like that? without having to declare static? ... thats kind of neat

Comment: Yes, in Python 3 an unbound method (i.e. a function in a class that you access via the class rather than an instance) is just a normal function. In Python 2, you'd get a special kind of bound method object, which would do a type check on the first argument (other than the check it still worked just like a normal function). The `staticmethod` decorator still exists so that you can call methods on instances without the instance being passed in when it's not wanted. I suppose that's the more complete answer: if you are going to keep the `miscellaneous` class, make everything a `staticmethod`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions within a Python class are called *methods*.  They normally take a `self` parameter before their other parameters.  Furthermore, methods *cannot "see" each other* directly; you need to call them as `self.method(args)` instead of just `method(args)`.