# Function not defined error when being called

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

so im returning two inputs and want to use them within another function, when i run the code, it says the function im returning the code from is not defined. any idea what the problem may be?

Chessboard Class:

```
class ChessBoard(tk.Frame):
       def __init__(self, parent, rows=8, columns=8, size=70, color1="white", color2="lightgrey"):

       self.rows = rows
       self.columns = columns
       self.size = size
       self.color1 = color1
       self.color2 = color2
       self.pieces = {}
```

The function that is returning two inputs:

```
    def UserInput(self): #Tester Function

      count = 0

      while count < 2:

          KingRow = int(input("Choose Row: ")) #mighht not be needed
          KingColumn = int(input("Choose Column: ")) #choose the column

      return KingRow, KingColumn

      count = count + 1
```

The function i would like to use it within:

```
def KingMoves(self, rows, columns):

    FinalMove = []

    c = ChessBoard(parent)

    KingRow, KingColumn = c.UserInput()

    FinalMove.append(((KingRow - 1),(KingColumn))) 
    FinalMove.append(((KingRow + 1),(KingColumn))) 
    FinalMove.append(((KingRow),(KingColumn + 1))) 
    FinalMove.append(((KingRow + 1),(KingColumn + 1))) 
    FinalMove.append(((KingRow - 1),(KingColumn + 1))) 
    FinalMove.append(((KingRow + 1),(KingColumn - 1))) 
    FinalMove.append(((KingRow - 1),(KingColumn - 1))) 

    return FinalMove;
```

Current Error:

```
    name 'UserInput' is not defined
```

Comment: Why the `self`?  Are these members of a class?

Comment: @StephenRauch yes the functions are, ive just cut them down so there isnt alot to read through.

Comment: Well you cut them down to the point of not being able to answer. You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @StephenRauch ive updated the code

Comment: Where is the class definition? You added a bunch of stuff that is not needed to reproduce the problem.  Please read through the links I commented earlier.

Comment: @StephenRauch the codes been reupdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you invoke the `ChessBoard` class, Python doesn't know where/what the `UserInput` function is. First invoke the class, and then call its function :

```
c = ChessBoard()
KingRow, KingColumn = c.UserInput()
```

Comment: says im missing a positional argument "parent", when i add parent in, it says that it is not defined.

Comment: Great @sharjeel, that means we are getting closer to the solution. Can you update the question to include how exactly you add parent in?

Comment: @sharjeel Call the class like this: root = tk.Tk() and then c = ChessBoard(root). Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this first: [how to use a Python function with keyword “self” in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472904/how-to-use-a-python-function-with-keyword-self-in-arguments)

**If that doesn't work try this:**

Functions within a Python class are called methods. They normally take a `self` parameter before their other parameters. Furthermore, methods cannot "see" each other directly; you need to call them as `self.method(args)` instead of just `method(args)`.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640592/python3-function-not-defined-even-though-it-is)

---

See, this is how I call another functions within a class:

```
def func1(self):
    return "Whoop"

def func2(self):
    whoop = self.func1()
    return whoop
```

Also, try using a `for` statement instead of a `while`. You don't have too, but it's less lines of code and easier.

```
def UserInput(self): #Tester Function
    for x in range(0, 2):
        KingRow = int(input("Choose Row: ")) #mighht not be needed
        KingColumn = int(input("Choose Column: ")) #choose the column

  return KingRow, KingColumn
```